# SQL query for converting column breaks in a single column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database in postgres where one of the columns contains text data with multiple column breaks.

So, when I export the data into csv file, the columns are jumbled!

I need a query which will ignore the column breaks in a single column and give an output where the data in the column is available in the same column and does not extend to the next column.

Comment: I don't understand your requirement, because I can't actually see your data.  That being said, can you include some sample data?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen he needs a query that ignores line breaks(in column line breaks) when transferred to CSV

Answer (score 0):

This example table exhibits the problem you are talking about:

```
test=> SELECT * FROM breaks;
┌────┬───────────┐
│ id │    val    │
├────┼───────────┤
│  1 │ text with↵│
│    │ three    ↵│
│    │ lines     │
│  2 │ text with↵│
│    │ two lines │
└────┴───────────┘
(2 rows)
```

Then you can use the `replace` function to replace the line breaks with spaces:

```
test=> SELECT id, replace(val, E'\n', ' ') FROM breaks;
┌────┬───────────────────────┐
│ id │        replace        │
├────┼───────────────────────┤
│  1 │ text with three lines │
│  2 │ text with two lines   │
└────┴───────────────────────┘
(2 rows)
```